# How to write value to different cell

Tags: angular

I have this pieco of code

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr *ngFor="let el of elements">       
       <td>{{el.name}}</td><td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

There is also a level property on the el object. It's a number type. I'd like to to write the el.name value to a cell according to the el.level value. For example if level value is 1 = cell 1, 2 = cell 2 and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have much levels, you can do something like this:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr *ngFor="let el of elements">       
        <td><span *ngIf="el.lvl == 1">{{el.name}}</span></td>
        <td><span *ngIf="el.lvl == 2">{{el.name}}</span></td>
        <td><span *ngIf="el.lvl == 3">{{el.name}}</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's see if something like this works - i didn't test it:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr *ngFor="let el of elements" #thisRow (onload)=setChildContent(thisRow, el)>
        <td></td><td></td><td></td> // leave it empty!
    </tr>
</table>
```

then in your component.ts file you have this function

```
export class SmartAnswerComponent {

    // this function will be called for each row as soon as it loads

    setChildContent(thisRow, el){
        let childIndex = el.lvl // or whatever property gives you the index
        let parent = thisRow // dumb code but good for explaining

        parent[childIndex].innerText = el.name; // here you set the name in the cell you want -assuming that the cell was previously created.
    }
}
```

I see that you have manually set 3 columns. It's normal - a table with 3 columns - nothing fancy.

But If you want to generate the number of columns(cells) dynamically - based on el.lvl than you just make a function which will take the el with the maximum lvl. This is expected if we have a normal bootstrap table. Number of cells shoud be the same on each row..

```
getTheNumberOfColumnsInThisTable(elements){
   let maxLvlNumber = elements.map(el => el.lvl) // here you get an array with only the levels.
   .reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => {
       if(previousValue < currentValue){
          return currentValue;
       }else{
          return previousValue;
       }
   }, 0 )
   let arrayWithMaxLvlNumberElements =  Array(maxLvlNumber).fill().map((x,i)=>i); // we can't iterate in *ngFor over a number like MaxLvlNumberElements,  so instead we create an array with that many elements.
   return arrayWithMaxLvlNumberElements;

}
```

Then you use this function to create an empty list of columns like this:

```
    // in your component.ts you do:
    this.numberOfColumns = getTheNumberOfColumnsInThisTable(this.elements)


    // in your component.html you do:
    <table class="table table-bordered">

       <tr *ngFor="let el of elements" #thisRow (onload)=setChildContent(thisRow, el)> // rows created.

       <td *ngFor="let oneColumn of numberOfColumns"></td> // cells created. -> don't do anything here. Leve them empty. the setChildContent() function will fill them.
        // of course this will give you the same number of cells(columns) on each row.
       </tr>
    </table>
```

If you don't want the same number of columns on each row you can change the cell creation code like this:

```
<td *ngFor="let eachCell of el.lvl "></td> // el.lvl can't be a number so transformeit in array as above.
```

Answer (score 0):

can't do it in a nice manner. you would have to create additional property on el that will be array with length of el.level eg.

```
el.levels = Array(el.level).fill(someValue)
```

than in template

```
<td *ngFor="let l of levels; let isLast=last">{{(isLast) ? el.name: ''}}</td>
```